# Changing statement causes lose of data

Tags: php

I need to change my echo statement below from

this

> php part

```
<?php
  $results = $GameQ->process();
?>
```

> html part

```
<tr class="active">
 <td><?php echo $results[$ID]['gq_hostname']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

to this

```
$results = $GameQ->process();   
 echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$ID.'["gq_hostname"]</td>
       </tr>';
```

The very first php and html part uptop works great what I am trying to change it to does not.

Comment: Change `$ID.'["gq_hostname"]` to `$results[$ID]['gq_hostname'];` ;)

Comment: `<td>' . $results[$ID]['gq_hostname'] . '</td>`

Comment: thanks guys I was banging my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
$results = $GameQ->process();   
echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$results[$ID]["gq_hostname"].'</td>
    </tr>';
```